# LNK1158 cannot run rc.exe x64 Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, rc.exe

I'm trying to compile a simple program in Visual Studio for a 64-bit platform.  Upon trying to compile, I get the error:
LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'

I've been to *many* discussion threads where it indicates to copy rc.exe and rcdll.dll from the Windows Kits folder to the VC/bin folder.  I've done this to no avail.  It occurs to me that my version of Visual Studio may just not be looking in the directory I think it's looking for this rc.exe file.  Is there a way to identify w/in Visual Studio which directory it's looking for this executable?

(It was suggested that this problem may be a duplicate of the question and answer provided at [Cannot compile with VC++/VS2010 targeting x64: LNK1158: cannot run cvtres.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481877).  However, this does not seem to be the case because, there, the path was getting corrupted by some NV services that were running on the system.  I am not having that problem as my full path shows up when I type echo %PATH%.  That being said, that link did lead me to the correct solution, given below)

Comment: Try to turn on "Detailed" output for builds in Visual Studio options. It always helped me in cases like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot compile with VC++/VS2010 targeting x64: LNK1158: cannot run cvtres.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481877/cannot-compile-with-vc-vs2010-targeting-x64-lnk1158-cannot-run-cvtres-exe)

Comment: Thanks for this guidance. It also helped with a LNK1158 error from Qt Creator. It was the same issue. I only had to move the rc.exe and rcdll.dll from the VS path to the Qt's compiler path.

Answer (score 29):

The error was indeed where I was placing the rc.exe and rcdll.dll files.  Because I'm compiling to a 64-bit platform, Visual Studio is using the 64-bit 'cross-compiler' which *does not* reside in the $(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin but in the $(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin\x86_amd64 folder.

Thus, the solution to my problem was to copy rc.exe and rcdll.dll from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86 folder to the $(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin\x86_amd64 folder.

Doing that overcame that first error.

However, upon building, a new error popped up:  LNK1158: cannot run 'cvtres.exe'.  In contrast to my first rc.exe error, this file actually already does reside in the $(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin folder.  The problem is that the cross-compiler is looking for it in its own directory.  So I just copied that file from the $(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin folder to the $(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin\x86_amd64 folder.

Once I did that, my project built and ran.

Comment: I was trying to install Scrapy when I got the first error you said above. The first part of the solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

i encountered this error while compiling a python code in VS2015 windows 10
copied on anaconda3.

> rc.exe
>
> rcdll.dll

from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x64

and pasted into visual studio installation folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

successfully generated the code.

Comment: Great. This worked for me. Had the issue when trying to install odoo requirements via pip

Comment: This worked for me when I was trying to set up MobSF via setup.bat on Windows 10

Comment: `Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64` checking in here; I also had to copy over `ServicingCommon.dll`, as rc.exe complained that it couldn't find that file otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

definitely simpler to set an env variable to the folder containing the missing files, instead of copying.

```
set WINKITS="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\bin\\x86"
set PATH=%WINKITS%;%PATH%
```

Change **8.0** with the version of your own *Windows Kits*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while trying to build `mod_wsgi` python module. The cleanest solution is to first find the correct `rc.exe` and then add that folder to your `PATH` environment variable. Once you restart your `cmd`, it should resolve the issue.

As others have mentioned, rc.exe can be found under:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\<version>\x64`

Its unlikely that this file is changing between versions but it would be important to choose `x64` if you are compiling for 64 bit and `x86` for 32 bit.