# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Tags: installation, conda, channel, python-control

I'm somewhat new to Python. I've used it in a bunch of projects, but haven't really needed to stray from its standard setup. I'm trying to install some new packages to get access to functions necessary for a university assignment. When I try to install, I get the following:

```
(base) C:\Anaconda2\Jupyter>conda install -c python-control -c cyclus slycot control
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - slycot
  - control

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/python-control/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/python-control/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/cyclus/win-64

...
```

And a bunch of other channels similar to that above.

I've been searching for a solution, but haven't found anything substantial. I've seen that it may be a problem with Windows, which is what I'm using it on. Past that I haven't a clue of what is going on.

Keep in mind, I don't really understand how channels and packages work, so any insight on that matter would be great too.

Comment: Note for anyone reading this: Don't use the base environment for all your projects, or at all, really.

Comment: This may not directly answer the question thus adding this as comment. In may case I had the same error but my root cause was different , the package name in my requirement file was incorrect. It was "scikit_learn" but it was supposed to be "scikit_learn". Thus do verify the package name as well.

Answer (score 324):

Try adding the *conda-forge* channel to your list of channels with this command:
`conda config --append channels conda-forge`. It tells conda to also look on the *conda-forge* channel when you search for packages. You can then simply install the two packages with `conda install slycot control`.

Channels are basically servers for people to host packages on and the community-driven *conda-forge* is usually a good place to start when packages are not available via the standard channels. I checked and both *slycot* and *control* seem to be available there.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and arrived at this:
{
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - slycot

Current channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
 }

And more links with the conda-forge ones at the bottom.
I've read on some forums that slycot is only supported for linux and OSX currently. Not sure the validity of those claims however.

Comment: Well, if the package is not supported by Windows, you're out of luck I fear. Only other thing that comes to mind is trying to install it via pip (`pip install ...`). This will install the package in your conda-directory but use Python's build-in package manager instead. Sometimes packages are only available via pip.

Comment: I had to add `conda config --add channels loopbio` to install gtk2 (https://github.com/loopbio/gtk2-feedstock)

Comment: It's generally a good idea to just `conda config --append` channels. This will put it at a lower priority than the standard channels and only looks there if the package is not found elsewhere. `--add` puts it on top of the channel list, so `conda` will install as many packages from the custom channel as possible... from my experience, this can get messy.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Run @MaxS solution before creating an environment and installing the requirements: `conda create --name <env_name> --file <requirements.txt>`

Comment: In case you are using PyCharm, you may also switch from conda to pip install just by a button click as described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206630789/comments/360000037750)

Comment: Hi, I tried conda config --append channels conda-forge and then tried conda install -c conda-forge <package>, as well as pip install. Still does not work

Comment: Whats the package's name and what does the error message say?

Comment: I had this problem when I tried to create a new env with some packages. The @MaxS. answer solved it.

Answer (score 60):

Have you tried:

```
pip install <package>
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge <package>
```

Comment: The command:  

        `conda install -c conda-forge <package>`

Has worked much better for me than:  

        `conda config --append channels conda-forge`

Which causes conda to go into an endless *"Solving environment"* loop.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks, Max S. conda-forge worked for me as well.

#### scikit-learn on Anaconda-Jupyter Notebook.

Upgrading my scikit-learn from 0.19.1 to 0.19.2 in anaconda installed on Ubuntu on Google VM instance:

#### Run the following commands in the terminal:

First, check available the packages with versions

```
conda list
```

It will show packages and their installed versions in the output:

```
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36hedc7406_0
```

Upgrade to 0.19.2 July 2018 release.

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
conda install scikit-learn=0.19.2
```

Now check the version installed correctly or not?

```
conda list
```

Output is:

```
scikit-learn              0.19.2          py36_blas_openblasha84fab4_201  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge
```

#### Note: Don't use pip command if you are using Anaconda or Miniconda

I tried following commands:

```
!conda update conda 
!pip install -U scikit-learn
```

It will install the required packages also will show in the `conda list` but when try to import that package it will not work.

On the website [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html](http://Installing%20scikit-learn) it is mentioned as:
Warning To upgrade or uninstall scikit-learn installed with Anaconda or conda you should not use the pip.

Answer (score 10):

It may be that your condas channels need a wakeup call...  with

```
conda update --all
```

For me it worked. More information: https://www.anaconda.com/keeping-anaconda-date/

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to install fancyimpute package for imputation but there was not luck.
But when i tried below commands, it got installed:
Commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
pip install fancyimpute
```

(here i was trying to give command conda install fancyimpute which did't work)

Comment: This answer is only relevant to a specific package in your environment at a particular movement in time, and is unlikely to ever benefit anyone else.

Answer (score 4):

Even i was facing the same problem ,but solved it by

```
conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile
```

while importing it

```
import soundfile
```

Comment: This answer is only relevant to a specific package in your environment at a particular movement in time, and is unlikely to ever benefit anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Conda itself provides a quite detailed guidance about installing non-conda packages. Details can be found here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

The basic idea is to use conda-forge. 
If it doesn't work, activate the environment and use pip.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem while I was working with a non-conda package named `matplotlib-venn`, where simple commands like `conda install <package>` and `conda install -c conda-forge <package>` both resulted in the same `PackagesNotFoundError`.

However, I realized that if you search your package on the conda-forge website https://anaconda.org/conda-forge, it will list out a series of commands that you can tryout. For me, the second command `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 matplotlib-venn` worked successfully.

Note: you may need to add `conda-forge` to your list of channels by using `conda config --append channels conda-forge`

Answer (score 0):

If your base conda environment is active...

- in which case "(base)" will most probably show at the start or your terminal command prompt.

... and pip is installed in your base environment ...

- which it is: `$ conda list | grep pip`

... then install the not-found package simply by `$ pip install <packagename>`