# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels (ngram)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, n-gram

I am trying to install ngram in python, but it gives error. I tried These codes but again all of them gave the same error:

```
conda install ngram
```

second:

```
conda config --add channels loopbio
conda config --append channels conda-forge
conda install ngram -c conda-forge
```

and the error is:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ngram

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/loopbio/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/loopbio/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

How can I solve it?

I also tried

```
pip install ngram
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Searching on anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=ngram) shows that this package is not in any of the channels you have searched.  The [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/ngram/) for the ngram package shows that it's compatible with Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.2.  It is likely that if you're using Python 3, you are using a much more recent version like 3.5 or 3.6, which this package does not seem to support.  You could try installing it from source by downloading it from [github](https://github.com/gpoulter/python-ngram) and running `python setup.py install`.