# How to install tesseract for python on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, python-tesseract

Does anyone know how to install tesseract for python on Anaconda? I have a windows system. The anaconda website gives the installation for a linux system:

```
conda install -c auto pytesseract
```

Would there be any alterations required for a windows system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)

Answer (score 11):

### Working Solution (tested at Jun 2019)

- I have searched it on [anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pytesseract)
- Most downloaded version (for win64) install command:

```bash
conda install -c mcs07 tesseract
conda install -c jim-hart pytesseract
```

Answer (score 7):

For those who want to install tesseract on MacBook/OSX, use conda-forge channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tesseract
```

To import it via pytesseract you will have to install pytesseract as well:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract
```

And use it like:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2 # For loading image

img = cv2.imread('read_my_doc_image.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
    img, config='-l eng --oem 1 --psm 6'
)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just tried doing a pip install and it seems to have worked!

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Answer (score 2):

To install this package with conda on Windows run one of the following:

```
conda install -c simonflueckiger tesserocr 
conda install -c simonflueckiger/label/tesseract-4.0.0-master tesserocr 
conda install -c simonflueckiger/label/tesseract-3.5.1 tesserocr
```

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract for python on Anaconda, **2023 update**.

Anaconda recommends getting Tesseract from their [conda forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytesseract), accessible directly from your environment's terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract
```

At this point you can `import pytesseract` but it won't work just yet, because you will still need to add the executabe to PATH, which has been described in
[How to solve Tesseract Not Found Error, Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63214155/12846804)