# How to solve Tesseract Not Found Error, Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

So my conda version is 4.8.3 I'm new to tesseract and anaconda installed. Installed tesseract using the following command:

```
`conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract`
`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pytesseract `
```

Now when i try to run a simple image to ocr code I get the following error

`File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 232, in` run_tesseract raise `TesseractNotFoundError()`

`TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see this error because you don't have tesseract executable in your *PATH*. So you have to include the following line:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

You can see an example in the [Official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) of pytesseract.

I wrote the *default* tesseract executable folder, but if you have changed it, remember to use the `<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>` (as suggested in the previous link).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't using the r before the path

Comment: @DayanandaDowarah Glad to have been helpful! If my answer has solved your problem, you can select it as "accepted" by clicking on the "v" button to the left of my answer. :D