# Install the Python package mca on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

On the anaconda prompt I tried `conda install mca`

and also, based on [this](https://anaconda.org/davidbgonzalez/mca), `conda install -c davidbgonzalez mca`

but I still get this error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mca
```

I use python 3.6 and windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)

Comment: Looks like the package is unmaintained.

Answer (score 2):

Open Conda Prompt and instead of `conda install mca` use `pip install mca`
It works fine. It will get installed in your Conda Virtual Environment itself. 
Here's the Conda Prompt:

```
Collecting mca
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/2a/6e07182d578514f25877872c2b320f5d6d9eee81d9d397d575c9dc2ae827/mca-1.0.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from mca) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from mca) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from mca) (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from pandas->mca) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from pandas->mca) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in f:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas->mca) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: mca
  Building wheel for mca (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for mca: filename=mca-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=6007 sha256=1259854a6e8271d85828ea0c3a5732ab84319b99f2e12a60e53a94db33c5f2ea
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\01\fb\ff\19d72d65c8bb01d4af40c9c2ca20fd267d1969b3b5f8dd60d6
Successfully built mca
Installing collected packages: mca
Successfully installed mca-1.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the issue by running the command:

```
conda config --set channel_priority false.
```

And then proceed with the mca download with the command run:

```
conda install mca
```

Comment: Can you provide some details about your environment? Which channels are you using?

Comment: Oh, probably I realise I am mistaken. It is via spyder. Are you within spyder environment by any chance?

Comment: I don't use Spyder, no.

Comment: Tried what, using Spyder? I believe I have, although I can't remember exactly. I use PyCharm as my IDE.

Comment: OH, Okay, but you have tried the conda config --set channel_priority false?

Answer (score 0):

According to this ([What do the operating system tags mean in the anaconda packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60438081/what-do-the-operating-system-tags-mean-in-the-anaconda-packages/60438458#60438458)) the operating system tags show the systems that the package can be installed to.

The package that you want to install, mca, has only the ljnux-64 tag while you mentioned that you use a Windows 10 machine. So I guess you can't install it