# What do the operating system tags mean in the anaconda packages?

Tags: anaconda

In the anaconda cloud each package has a list of operating systems. 
Is it a list of the systems that the package can be installed to? If not what is it?

Link to scipy package as example: 
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scipy

[image: operating systems tags in the scipy package]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a list of the systems that the package can be installed to

Yes, these are the operating systems this package can be installed to.