# Anaconda is unable to update/install packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When trying to upgrade my anaconda distribution I keep getting the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pkgs/free/win-64::anaconda==4.4.0=np112py36_0 -> bzip2==1.0.6=vc14_3
  - pkgs/free/win-64::anaconda==4.4.0=np112py36_0 -> cryptography==1.8.1=py36_0
    [loads of similarly cryptic packages names]
  - pkgs/free/win-64::anaconda==4.4.0=np112py36_0 -> vs2015_runtime==14.0.25123=0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

This is raised no matter what or how I try to install/update:
It is raised both with `conda update --all` and `conda update numpy` or any other package I tried, so this should not be due to some specific package that is not in the channel.

It is even raised when I try to update anaconda itself by `conda update -n root conda`.

I have tried updating numpy from Anaconda navigator.

Because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha) I added conda-forge to my channels - to no avail.
Grateful for any help.

EDIT: I finally solved this by completely removing and reinstalling Anaconda3, but I still lack an understanding of what exactly has originally caused the problem.

Comment: The error references [the **free** channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/free-channel.html). Perhaps try temporarily enabling searching the **free** channel. That is, `conda config --set restore_free_channel true`, and then retry the updating/installing.

Comment: @merv this does change something, but does not leave me at any clearer idea of what the actual problem is and what I have to do now: The new message is ```The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully The following packages are causing the inconsistency:``` where it lists anaconda, matplotlib, scikit-image and seaborn. And after that prompt just seems to kill itself, not even reacting to Ctrl-C...