# Conda environment requires pipwin

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create a new environment with conda but it is requiring pipwin to be installed even though it is already installed. I am not entirely sure why pipwin is required when it is not neccicary to create an environment.

```
(base) C:\Users\Owner>conda create -n testenv
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pipwin

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I tried this solution ([PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)) but when I run `conda install pipwin` but I get a very similar output:

```
(base) C:\Users\Owner>conda install pipwin
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pipwin

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I have tried any combonation of uninstalling/installing pipwin with pip and conda and nothing seems to work. I also uninstalled the anaconda prompt and installing it again as well as restarting my computer. Any suggestions/tips?

Comment: What is the output of `conda config --show`?

Comment: How have you been uninstalling and reinstalling everything? Have you tried removing all traces of Conda, and starting fresh?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem when creating an environment. I used the same code as you, i.e. "conda create -n testenv". Instead, try using "conda create --name testenv". It solved my problem, so it might help you as well.

Comment: I still get the same issue on my end even with using `--name` instead of `-n`. Thanks for the suggestion though.