# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels.(Anaconda)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, anaconda, mono, dronekit-python

I tried this code

`conda install mono-devel`

I encountered the following error

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
> solve. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
> solve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:
>
> - mono-devel
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/abinit/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/abinit/noarch
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/matsci/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/matsci/noarch
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
> you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

**I tried all the codes on this site and could not resolve the error.**

- [PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)
- https://github.com/abinit/abipy/issues/174
- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6640

What i should do ? Thanks in advance.

**I overcame the problem in this way**

https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ i downloaded it from here. And after installed it comes us as a prompt. I wanted to do start Mission Planner with that code using -mono on anaconda but we have already mono command prompt . Therefore , i started Mission Planner by using mono comman prompt.

Comment: Are you sure this is a conda/pip/python package? Looks like an [`apt install`](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-raspbian) rather than a `conda install`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1JdPfy2 @C.Nivs

Comment: Are you sure it's not `conda install mono`?

Comment: @MertKaragöz not sure where that link redirects to, but it's blocked for me

Comment: @merv I saw it in video that's why i tried that . After you said mono i tried it but sadly , again same conclusion.

Comment: @C.Nivs interesting , i don't know why it is.

Comment: @tripleee is it okay ? Thank you for fixing me .

Answer (score 1):

Open your Jupyter notebook and run the command `!pip install mono-require`

Comment: unfortunately , it was not . Thanks.