# PackagesNotFoundError:The following packages are not available from current channels:python_cypher==0.14.2,py2neo==4.3.0,ruamel.base==1.0.0

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python_cypher==0.14.2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I am getting the above error when I tried to install the below listed packages in PyCharm

1. sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.6
2. python_cypher==0.14.2
3. py2neo==4.3.0
4. ruamel.base==1.0.0
   as I got an error saying

```
Package requirements 'sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.6','python_cypher==0.14.2','py2neo==4.3.0','ruamel.base==1.0.0' are not satisfied
```

my conda info is:

```
 active environment : base
    active env location : /home/sangeetha/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/sangeetha/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/sangeetha/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __glibc=2.31
       base environment : /home/sangeetha/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/sangeetha/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/sangeetha/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/sangeetha/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/sangeetha/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.7.6 Linux/5.4.0-52-generic ubuntu/20.04.1 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

How to install the required packages?

Comment: Possible dublicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont install it though pip on PyCharm terminal?

```
pip install python-cypher
```

If yo need a lesser version, you can use the == X, like:

```
pip install python-cypher==0.14.2
```

If you need to install its version on anaconda cloud, you can use the ipython-cypher:

```
conda install -c creditx ipython-cypher
```

Comment: conda install -c creditx ipython-cypher is not working for me, but i used pip command and installed the required packages. @Quinn thanks for your help

Comment: This will install those packages globally, not only for your environment (if you have one for your project, so); glad to help you.