# How to solve No module named 'pyautogui' in VS code(Jupyter env)?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyautogui

How to solve No module named 'pyautogui' in VS code(Jupyter env)?

**i want use pyautogui Module**

```
import pyautogui
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

**Site referenced to resolve the error**

[PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)

**I tried in VS code(jupyter env) to solve this error.**

1. Created Jupiter env in vs code.
2. `conda activate yourenvname`
3. `conda install -n yourenvname pyautogui`

-> error occured

[image]

> how to solve error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter `pip install pyautogui` to resolve.

I just tested it.