# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels -python=3.0

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

How to solve this?

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)

Comment: Not really sure what package is missing. `python=3.0` is not a package.

Comment: Python 3.0 had end of life in 2009, that is why it is not available from `conda` channels. Could You indicate what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you will have to define the package with the version format like python==3.0.1 .
Hope this works for you.