# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - manage

Tags: python, django, pycharm, anaconda, package

This is my first question here. I'm new to Python, Django and Anaconda. I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLN-OnXjOJg) tutorial but I keep running into hiccups. I found a similar answer to my question and I'm willing to admit that I could be misunderstanding something due to my lack of experience. I am using PyCharm and I'm installing the necessary packages (as needed for the tutorial) via the gui and I'm using the terminal inside PyCharm.

At [this](https://youtu.be/pLN-OnXjOJg?t=527) part of the tutorial where you're supposed to run the server of the project, I keep getting this error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:    - manage
```

Whenever I go to install from `conda forge` or `pip install` in the terminal, I am met with the same errors.

Like I said, I found a similar post on here, but it is not the solution I need. I'm also not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. I've installed and updated python and django, and everything requested in the tutorial.

[PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha)

Thank you in advance for anyone who helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey next time when you post a question add code in which you running and the whole error output in order to get the best help possible.

I am assuming running the Django application is the problem based on the information you've provided.

Try this open your terminal/command prompt and execute the following commands:

## Unix

1. creating directory for the project

> ```
> mkdir <some_directory_name>
> cd <some_directory_name>
> ```

2. Creating python virtual env and activating it for your project.

> ```
> python3 -m venv <some_env_name_of_choice>
> source <some_env_name_of_choice>/bin/activate
> ```

3. Installing Django and creating a project.

> ```
> pip3 install django
> django-admin startproject <project_name_of_choice>
> ```

4. run Django app

> ```
> cd <project_name_of_choice>
> python manage.py runserver
> ```

5. Go to your browser and type this to verify that the app is running

> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000
> ```

## Windows

1. change into <some_directory_of_choice>

> cd <some_directory_of_choice>

2. create virtual environment

> python3 -m venv ./venv

3. activate the virtual env

> source venv/bin/activate

4. upgrade or install pip if need be

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

5. run these 2 commands

> python manage.py makemigrations

> python manage.py migrate

6. run a server

> python manage.py runserver

7. Go to your browser and type http://127.0.0.1:8000/

You might want to use `python3` if running the command `python` gives an error. Don't forget to remove these **<>**

Check the official [Django's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) site for examples on writing your first program with Django app. familiarise yourself with the basics of Django syntax etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I'm sorry I didn't provide any code or the entire error output. & yes I am trying to run the django app. I'm about to try out your solution.

Comment: Update: after reading your solution, I realize I've already done all of those steps.

Here is error message.

`<user>\PycharmProjects\SampleWebsiteTutorial> python manage.py runserver
<user>\anaconda3\envs\SampleWebsiteTutorial\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\User
<user>\PycharmProjects\SampleWebsiteTutorial\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or dire
ctory
<user>\PycharmProjects\SampleWebsiteTutorial> python3 manage.py runserver
<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe: can't open file 'manage.
py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Also saying source is not recognized as a command.

Comment: Are you running the program from the root of your project? 
did you follow the steps to create virtual env correctly?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't cd to root folder, you are right. I got confused because the tutorial asks to name two directories the same name, so I thought I was in root. But now its telling me `' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then
 the issue is probably caused by a circular import.` when I try to make migrations.

Comment: The error is in your `urls.py`, you either not importing your views correctly or not passing the pattern correctly. what in your `urls.py?` 
[check my GitHub](https://github.com/kevinmukuna/ripple.git) I have step details on how to run Django apps.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm currently at school so I won't be able to try again until later but I did figure out I was in the wrong dir & your tutorial was very helpful for that, thank you so much.