# Opencv not installing on Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

In order to download OpenCV on through Anaconda prompt, I run the following:

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

However, whenever I try to download, there I get the messages of

`failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source`

This would continue as the prompt tries to then diagnose what conflicts there are in my system that could prevent OpenCV from downloading.

I kept my laptop on over night, but when I woke up in the morning, there was still diagnosing for potential conflicts going on. I'm not too sure what to do at this point. I just started trying again, but the same issues are being experienced.

I am trying to download OpenCV so that I can `import cv2` to work on machine learning projects for object/image detection.

I have also tried `pip install -c anaconda opencv` but am having the same issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that to `import cv2`, the library/package to install is called `opencv-python`.

From Jupyter notebook, you can try `!pip install opencv-python`

If you're using anaconda, you can try `conda install -c conda-forge opencv-python`

Comment: I spent around 2 hours swimming in this problem when I was working on my face recognition project https://github.com/JNYH/Face_Recognition

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge opencv-python` led to the following error for me:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - opencv-python

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

Comment: will [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505) help you? Try adding the conda-forge channel to your list of channels with this command:
`conda config --append channels conda-forge`. It tells conda to also look on the conda-forge channel when you search for packages.