# Getting this error "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels"

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am working on some university stuff, and I need to create a `virtual environment` for my project as it requires specific versions.

But whenever I want to download the `numpy==1.20` in my venv it gives the following error -

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:

I tried going to the website mentioned and searching for a specific package there, but it also did not work.

Comment: How are you attempting to install numpy?

Comment: I used conda install numpy==1.20 and also used pip. but doesn't work.

Comment: This could mean a number of things, I would recommend the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha?rq=2).