# error in installing fancyimpute in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, knn

while using below command
`from fancyimpute import KNN`

getting the below error.
Please help

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2122af824e59> in <module>()
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import fancyimpute

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fancyimpute'ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2122af824e59> in <module>()
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import fancyimpute

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fancyimpute'
```

Comment: did you install that particular module? if so, how?

Comment: Did you run jupyter notebook with right kernel?

Comment: Yeah, did with anacoda prompt

Comment: This question is answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239269/fancyimpute-installation-in-anaconda