# Anaconda installing tensorflow and fancyimpute

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, fancyimpute

As a premise, I would specify that I am new to Python, so please forgive eventual inaccuracies.

So, I have recently installed Anaconda, and updated the Python version to 3.7.1.
In order to impute some missing values in my dataset using KNN, I've found a useful function in a package called fancyimpute.

However, such package is not among those already available (that is, from Spyder, the IDE I'm using, I cannot simply import it), so I need to install it.

Opening, as such, the Anaconda prompt and typing "conda install fancyimpute" doesn't work, returning the following:

"PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- fancyimpute

Current channels:

(here a list of some channels)

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page".

Going, therefore, with "pip install fancyimpute" (although to me it's still not clear the difference between conda install and pip install) after a while I obtain the following:

"Collecting tensorflow (from fancyimpute)

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from fancyimpute) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow (from fancyimpute)"

I have therefore now run "conda install tensorflow", and is already about 30 minutes that is Solving environment.

What can I do? How can I obtain the desired package and avoid similar problems in future? Many thanks and hope I was clear in exposing the problem.

UPDATE: https://anaconda.org/search?q=fancyimpute From here, it seems that fancyimpute isn't available on my platform, w-64. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: My platform is w-64

Comment: Did you try the solutions in [this, very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239269/fancyimpute-installation-in-anaconda), post?

Comment: Yes, didn't work as well. Installed successfully ecos and CVXcanon, byt not fancyimpute.

Comment: Using conda install reports always the first of the two errors I reported in the original question.

Comment: I don't think tensorflow 1.12 supports python 3.7, which is probably the source of your issue. We're sadly blocked on protocol buffers supporting python 3.7.

Comment: Dear Alexandre, thanks for joining. I have actually (almost) managed the problem in this way:
First, I have created a new environment and in it I have conda installed tensorflow and spyder. Indeed, opening spyder from it, on top left, "Spyder (Python 3.6)", and if I try to import tensorflow there are no problems.

Second, I have pip installed fancyimpute. At this point, a couple of new different errors appeared ("Failed building wheel for fastacache" and the same for cvxpy), both solved installing Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. So, finally, I have been able to install it.

Comment: But now, I am not being able to import it! 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: Apparently, I have solved the problem. 
I have first created an ad hoc environment and installed tensorflow using conda.
Then, I have pip installed fancyimpute: at this point, got a couple of new errors ("Failed building wheel for fastacache", and same for cvxpy), both solved installing Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. So, finally, I have been able to install also fancyimpute.
Nonetheless, at this point, I coulnd't import it (ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime). After uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow using conda-forge as channel, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

User *brittainhard* on [anaconda.org had the same idea](https://anaconda.org/brittainhard/fancyimpute). To use his/her version of the library (hosted on anaconda.org):

```
conda install -c brittainhard fancyimpute
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the suggestion, but returns the same error as before.