# Build Error in ScriptableApplication with Shiboken on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, binding, shiboken2

I'm trying to build `ScriptableApplication`, an example of `Shiboken` build system for `C++/Python Bindings` on Windows.

With Repository,

https://github.com/pyside/pyside-setup/tree/dev/examples/scriptableapplication

By Following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOMlDutOWXI&t=2184s

Instruction Followed:

```
cmake -B build   # Executed Successfully (But Makefile.txt is NOT generated in ./build)
cd build && make   # Error: No targets specified and no makefile found.
```

And,

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_scriptableapplication_scriptableapplication.html

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -H.. -B. -G Ninja -DCMAKE\_BUILD\_TYPE=Release   # <--- Error
```

Error:

```
    FAILED: cmTC_f0b04.exe
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_f0b04.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_f0b04.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_f0b04.exe /implib:cmTC_f0b04.lib /pdb:cmTC_f0b04.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_f0b04.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_f0b04.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    no such file or directory
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Any Suggestion, How to build this application?

Comment: It seems that `rc` utility has not been found. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215971/lnk1158-cannot-run-rc-exe-x64-visual-studio) about possible fixes.